# wpf debug error output System.WIndows.Data Error 25

Tags: wpf, debugging, combobox

I have a custom styled Combobox which works fine. It is placed inside a usercontrol and bound to a data structure. I use DisplayMemberPath to show only one element in the Combobox TextBox. The ComboBox Style is taken from MSDN and used many times. So it's not displayed here.

```
<UserControl x:Class="wpf.projext1.MyComboBox"
         x:Name="MyControl"
         ...
    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                  Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Text}"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                  StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=MyItemsSource}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    </ComboBox
```

I get the following annoying error message populating the output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 25 : Both 'ContentTemplate' and 'ContentTemplateSelector' are set;  'ContentTemplateSelector' will be ignored. ComboBoxItem:'ComboBoxItem' (Name='')
```

if i leave out the

```
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
```

... no debug output about error 25 is shown. But I definitely need DiplayMemberPath="Name"!
Do You have an idea to fix this ?

Comment: In your Style `ComboBoxStyle` you might be setting the `ItemTemplate` for you combobox. Hence, this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

resolved: use the TextSearch attached property, no matter if TextSearch is enabled!

```
TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
```

Answer (score 19):

You can´t set both `DisplayMemberPath` and `ItemTemplate` at the same time.

`DisplayMemberPath` is used to tell the ItemsControl which property to display when showing your objects. It makes no sense to set this field if you're already passing a custom `ItemTemplate`, since you can choose *how* to show the object within that ItemTemplate.

Since the default Combobox style from MSDN also sets an ItemTemplate, this is likely the cause of the error.

Comment: I have an itemtemplate that is used to show the ComboboxItems. It should also be used to display the content of the editbox ?

Comment: When I set DisplayMemebrPath, the combobox works like it should. When I leave it out, The editbox displays the default (classname) string. Do setting DisplaymemebrPath does really something useful, as setting an Itemtemplate for the ComboboxItems. So could you explain how to put it together, like you suggested ?

Comment: I must add that the editbox does NOT display a ComboboxItem like it is defined in the Itemtemplate. It does onle display the "Name" member. The ItemTemplate shows "Name" "Age" "Adress" etc for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Should note `TextSearch.TextPath="Name"` **instead of** `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`.