# ControlTemplate not using ContentTemplateSelector at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime, custom-controls, controltemplate

I've got a custom control `CheckableItemsControl` that I've thrown together, it's lookless, has no dependency properties of its own and just derives from `ItemsControl`.

Following Rachel's answer in this question: [How can I overwrite my ListBox's ItemTemplate and still keep the DisplayMemberPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486905/how-can-i-overwrite-my-listboxs-itemtemplate-and-still-keep-the-displaymemberpa) I've managed to come up with the following style in Generic.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:CheckableItemsControl}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckableItemsControl}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}" 
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector}"
                          Margin="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckableItemsControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Margin="0,0,0,3">
                        <Button x:Name="PART_SelectAllButton" Content="Select All" Width="60" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        <Button x:Name="PART_InvertButton" Content="Invert" Width="60" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And using it is like this:

```
<controls:CheckableItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}" DisplayMemberPath="ReportName" />
```

Now, this works just fine at design time, the designer correctly renders the items with their `ReportName` being displayed as text.

At runtime however, it just renders the type name like you'd expect with no content template.

I can't work out why this would fail at runtime.

Comment: Take a look at the output window and see if there are any errors occurring.

Comment: @CalebB Thanks! I'm getting `Both 'ContentTemplate' and 'ContentTemplateSelector' are set;  'ContentTemplateSelector' will be ignored. ContentPresenter:'ContentPresenter' (Name='')` but I'm not setting ContentTemplate...

Comment: @CalebB found the reason! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654935/wpf-debug-error-output-system-windows-data-error-25

Comment: Cheers, glad you found the solution. :)

Comment: @CalebB Just annoying, because it means I'll need to add my own way of lifting out the value without setting `ContentTemplate` *sigh*

Comment: Well it's a start and your on the right track now so happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it's down to this:

[wpf debug error output System.WIndows.Data Error 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654935/wpf-debug-error-output-system-windows-data-error-25)

Ultimately `ContentTemplateSelector` is being ignored because I've implicitly adopted a `ContentTemplate` by using `DisplayMemberPath`.

The solution will likely be adding a custom dependency property to pull out the value manually.

**Further information**:

From the [`ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> If both the `ContentTemplateSelector` and the `ContentTemplate` properties are set, then this property is ignored.